# How to specify path of AndroidManifest.xml file in <gettype> ant target?

Tags: android, ant

I have created build.xml in build folder. I want to create .apk file using build script.
I have used the required code from build.xml file stored under /android-sdks/tools/ant folder.

Now when I run debug target; I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified" error for  target; since now it cannot find AndroidManifest.xml file under /build folder.

Can anybody tell me where can I specify path of AndroidManifest.xml for android specific ant targets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't, at least (still) not yet.

`gettype.java` (see e.g. [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/1ad2af8eb043d1b6c600a9487ae5130e567104d7/anttasks/src/com/android/ant/GetTypeTask.java)) doesn't check the `manifest.file` *property*, but just an internal *constant*:

```
        File manifest = new File(antProject.getBaseDir(), SdkConstants.FN_ANDROID_MANIFEST_XML);
```

(See also [this blog entry](http://blog.uncommons.org/2010/07/19/building-two-versions-of-the-same-android-app/) about using multiple variants of the same code base, he had the same problem with his manifest files, and needed to copy them around to overcome it.)